# python 3.5.4 compiled by Pyinstaller, the builtin print() statement throws OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I have a `program.exe` file that is compiled with `pyinstaller` version 3.5 by running the command `pyinstaller --log-level DEBUG program.py`. `program.py` includes several `print(string_variables)` statements.

```py
# The codes below run 3 times per second, as it keeps receiving image data using a socket of TCP protocol.
log_text(time_now() + "Sent " + connCmd, log_to_disk=False)
# ...
log_text(time_now() + "Written to cur_image.jpg", log_to_disk=False)
# ...
```

```py
# project01\logger.py
    def log_text(self, text, log_to_disk=True):
        log_text = time_now() + str(text)

        try:
            print(log_text)
        except:
            self.log_to_txt(format_exc())
            self.log_to_txt("Print statement raised error while printing \'" + log_text + "\'")

        if log_to_disk:
            self.log_to_txt(log_text)

    def log_to_txt(self, content):
        try:
            with open(self.log_path, "a") as f:
                f.write(content + "\n")
        except Exception as e:
            # ... not shown as no exception has ever been caught here.
```

The errors look like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "project01\logger.py", line 36, in log_text
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Print statement raised error while printing '09/03/2020 09:22:28: Took 2 loops to receive the current image.'
09/03/2020 09:22:37: Received a TCP command signal.
09/03/2020 09:22:43: Received a TCP command signal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "project01\logger.py", line 36, in log_text
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Print statement raised error while printing '09/03/2020 09:22:45: Written to cur_image.jpg'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "project01\logger.py", line 36, in log_text
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Print statement raised error while printing '09/03/2020 09:22:59: Sent BBBB'
```

The same `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument` will occur about once every 20 seconds, and this continues for several hours, then it never happens for another couple of hours, and then it happens again for several hours, and so on.

I could not find a way to even make print() statement throw an `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument`. It couldn't possibly be because of any of the string variables that were passed into `print()` right? As all of them could be logged to disk. Any idea what could have caused the error?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the absolute path instead of relative path:

> /home/user name/folder/project01/logger.py

in ubuntu adding absolute paths working, in windows, I have the same problem